# Is it possible to combine columns and rows which are seperate in JSON, using JSONata or JSONPath?

Tags: json, jsonpath, jsonata

I want to use JSONata (https://try.jsonata.org/) or JSONPath to combine column data from a Columns array with row data from a Rows array in the same JSON. I think I need to have a for each row with another for each column nested inside. Can I do this using JSONata or JSONPath?

```
**INPUT**
{
  "Columns": [
    {
      "ColumnName": "Name",
      "ColumnType": "string"
    },
    {
      "ColumnName": "Id",
      "ColumnType": "int"
    }
  ],
  "Rows": [
    ["Alice", 1],
    ["Bob", 2],
    ["Carl", 3]
  ]
}

**OUTPUT**
{
  "combinedData": [
    {
      "Name": "Alice",
      "Id": 1
    },
    {
      "Name": "Bob",
      "Id": 2
    },
    {
      "Name": "Carl",
      "Id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: JSON Path is a query syntax.  It doesn't do transformations.  JSONata is a templating syntax.  It's likely closer to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create smaller objects, one for each key, then merge at the end.
[See Playground demo](https://www.stedi.com/jsonata/playground?statev2=eJyFkcFOwzAMhl%2FFsnpYpahiG1w4IMG4cOGAuCU5ZG2YIrVOlbTaUFuenWSpugkhODn57Py2%2F3CO3vau1MhQn1qnvTeWwkWNN%2BM6xEEQgMCdrfuGvMB74JEADClckq%2Bq0TEvMJ3Yz4L3z3Yu8J0zdBCYKib2r%2BJL9aeeoW4Ri0GyNPWbPV6PzAU%2B1qaMs8FasgU%2B2X1Emyu0U66ObCvPeoKm4IUgQbMfpW32hnT1rDoVO2RF7AVfD5A1ql199FR2wchV5uwxhwGScFbMPnJZXFb85RUFzCAzVOlTvvgynHloFkR5SsppXjtPKtoddCRTHkYW8SPtuBm34y1KhncovwHBFpSc)

```
{
  "combinedData": $.Rows ~> $map(function($row) { 
    $.Columns[].ColumnName ~> $map(function($name, $index){
      {$name: $row[$index]}
    }) ~> $merge
  })
}
```

Comment: This worked great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It could be done using some of the built-in operators and functions of JSONata:

```
{
  "combinedData": Rows.(
    $#$i.{
      $$.Columns[$i].ColumnName: $
    } ~> $merge
  )
}
```

Check it out live on the [Stedi Playground](https://www.stedi.com/jsonata/playground?statev2=eJyFkD0LwjAQhv9KODMohOLn4iD4sbg4iFuSIdZQAm0iSUXF6G%2FXmGKLok53uXt4781LKThzsKkEAvK0t9I5ZfTjIXzX9x71wjRCDOYmPxTaMRgjGiYIXWKplytRyLBnEDvyDmzO%2BwpwpVU6YxCJK%2FmruNz91FO6fImFwkl0vTbHpmVaK0xzlTY99mLDyQc5M9sG1%2F%2FKzYXNG%2BCgAp92mL7WUaam2CotdwtRimAumEzaEcctrJJXDhgnVe4UK57UoYwRrn6LbhOEC2kzGQadeMj4vh%2F4IXACI%2BB3QGKGAg%3D%3D)

Comment: This also did exactly what I was looking for.